# How to move array elements inside an object to end of the array

Tags: javascript

Here is our object:

```
let obj = {
  "I was sent":  ["I was sent", "I was forced"],
  "to earth": ["to earth", "to moon"],
  "to protect you": [ "to find you", "to protect you", "to love you"]

}
```

I want to move array elements based on the property name to the end of the array.

The desired result would be :

```
  let obj = {
      "I was sent":  ["I was forced", "I was sent"],
      "to earth": ["to moon", "to earth"],
      "to protect you": [ "to find you", "to love you", "to protect you"]

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of [key, value] pairs. Map the array, and for each pair, check for the index of key (`k`) in the value (`v`). If the index is found, move the key to end of the value. Convert the array back to an object via `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const obj = {
  "I was sent":  ["I was sent", "I was forced"],
  "to earth": ["to earth", "to moon"],
  "to protect you": [ "to find you", "to protect you", "to love you"]
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([k, v]) => {
    const index = v.findIndex(s => s === k)
    
    return [
      k,
      index > -1 ? [...v.slice(0, index), ...v.slice(index + 1), k] : v
    ]
  }))
  
console.log(result)
```

If the key is always found in the value, you can always filter it out, and add it to the end of the array:

```js
const obj = {
  "I was sent":  ["I was sent", "I was forced"],
  "to earth": ["to earth", "to moon"],
  "to protect you": [ "to find you", "to protect you", "to love you"]
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([k, v]) => {
    const newV = [...v.filter(s => s !== k), k]
    
    return [k, newV]
  }))
  
console.log(result)
```